# how to filter csv (excel file) when uploading to database

Tags: php, csv, file-upload, filtering

So this is the issue I have problems in filtering the csv content from characters like apostrophes I tried using str_replace but it doesn't seem to affect anything. the code below works perfectly when uploading data which has no special character in it particularly the apostrophe can you polish my code below so the system will not get an error because of special characters?

here is the **code**:

```
 if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = str_replace("'","",$_FILES[csv][tmp_name]); 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if (str_replace("'","",$data[0])) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO faculty(FCode,FName,MName,LName,Gender,image_name,BDate,Title,Service,EmpStat,CollegeID,DepartmentID,dateCreated) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]','$currentDate')") or die ("LOL" .mysql_error()); 

        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

here is a picture of the sample csv file https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcJ6T.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO faculty(FCode,FName,MName,LName,Gender,image_name,BDate,Title,Service,EmpStat,CollegeID,DepartmentID,dateCreated) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[10])."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[11])."','$currentDate')") or die ("error in sql syntax" .mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql_real_escape_string();

```
 mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO faculty(FCode) values('mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])')") or die ("LOL" .mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you sir I completely forgot about that